# How to create a google maps fragment in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I started programming for Android apps and it's pretty cool. I have the basic knowledge, but there is something I can't get working.

I would like to have on my detailActivity an Google Maps layout to show the location of something, like all airports. If I look over the internet there is a `Google Maps Activity`. This will create a activity with a Google Maps fragment and a fragment java file to handle the position of the map. I learned about fragments, but I can't find out how this one is build up. Normally you have an xml file with the markup that you will wrap in a fragment object, but now there is only the fragment.

What's the best method to include a google maps fragment into an activity that has already have some java code linked to it?

If someone has a great resource for this or some code examples would be nice. Already checked the Google site: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

I tried already the Google Map Activity. Copy the fragment out of `activity_maps.xml` then remove that file, place the copied fragment inside the `detailActivity`, but then I am stuck with the `MapsActivity` java file that handles the center point of the map etc. How should I edit this, so I can use the fragment inside `activity_main.xml`? There is already linked a java file to this xml file.

**DetailActivity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.casper.airports.DetailActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="193dp" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.casper.airports.MapsActivity" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**DetailActivity JAVA file**

```
    public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView responseName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        this.responseName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        initActivity();
    }

    private void initActivity() {

        // Development
        Log.i("initActivityContent", "");

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String response = (String) i.getSerializableExtra("CONTENT");

        Log.d("SelectedItem: ", response + "");

        initActivityContent(airport);

    }

    private void initActivityContent(String response) {

        responseName.setText(response);

    }

}
```

**Generated MapsActivity file for Google Maps**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: please check this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/  i hope this will help you

Comment: Yes absolutely! It's working.

Comment: A detailed example is here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html